# Shared_ptr cannot be initialized in constructor if `this` involved

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have some code structured like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct demo {
    vector<shared_ptr<demo>> foo{shared_ptr<demo>(this)};
    void append(){
        foo.push_back(make_shared<demo>());
    }
};

demo dummy(/* accept some arguments */){
    demo a{};
    a.append();
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    demo bar=dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

The dummy function just do some process based on its argument on a newly constructed demo instance and return it. *(I'm pretty sure that the above is enough to expose the problem)*

It compiles well with no error, however **it won't terminate it self**. (I'm using g++ of MinGW on Win7).

Then I try to work around. I added a copy constructor (as well as a explicit default constructor), and then use `new` to only keep a pointer to demo in main function. So the code will be something like:

```
...
struct demo {
    vector<shared_ptr<demo>> foo {shared_ptr<demo>(this)};
    void append() {
        foo.push_back(make_shared<demo>());
    }
    demo(){
    };
    demo(const demo& instance): foo(instance.foo) {
    }
};
...
int main()
{
//    demo bar=dummy();
    demo* bar=new demo(dummy());
    delete bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Then it just worked. But still I wonder the mechanism behind those lines. Would you just explain what's difference between the `new` constructed and normally declared variable?

**EDIT:** So finally is there anyway to `push_back` `this` into a vector as struct member in its constructor? (For the reason, it's because the rest of my vector stores all `shared_ptr` except the first one, in other words, even if the vector is `pop_back`ed to be empty, it could still return `this`)

Comment: `bar` isn't automatically deleted: `demo* bar=new demo(dummy());` it leaks.

Comment: You should avoid `shared_ptr<demo>(this)` (as you don't have guaranty of who own `this` before) `enable_shared_from_this` might help.

Comment: You can't take an object exclusively owned by someone else and decide that it's to be shared. Sharing must be a mutual agreement or things may go seriously awry.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Where did I do that? (I never mean that)

Comment: @YiFei `shared_ptr<demo>(this)` does that. You can use `std::enable_shared_from_this` and `std::shared_from_this` to get a `shared_ptr` but even then, `this` must already be managed by a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, so did you mean this is only available in the instance itself (that as you said *'exclusively owned by someone else'*)? I'm quite confused about what's been exclusively owned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more minimal example, that reproduces your problem:

```
struct demo {
    shared_ptr<demo> foo{this};
};

int main()
{
    demo bar;
}
```

The problem is that you store a shared pointer to `this`, in a member. So, when a `demo` instance is destroyed, the shared pointer is decremented, and when the shared pointer is decremented to zero, then it will delete the object again, causing undefined behaviour.

Even if that wasn't the problem, there is still the issue that `bar` is an automatic object. And you may not have shared pointers to automatic objects. But `bar` does create a shared pointer to itself.

```
demo* bar=new demo(dummy());
delete bar;
```

This is better, because now the object (pointed by `bar`) has dynamic storage, so you may have a shared pointer to it. You must of course fix `dummy` to not create an automatic `demo` instance as well.

Also, you may not explicitly `delete` an instance of `demo` because there is a shared pointing to itself inside. The "correct" way to dispose an instance of `demo` would be to remove the shared pointer, which would then take care of the deletion:

```
demo* bar=new demo(dummy());
bar->foo.clear();      // this is for your vector version
//bar->foo = nullptr;  // this is for my minimized example above
// object pointed by bar no longer exists
// (unless the shared pointer was copied and exists elsewhere)
```

However, I find this design very confusing, and would not recommend it. You should reconsider *why* you store a shared pointer to `this`.

Comment: Totally agree with the *undefined behavior* explanation. But as I tried, the code doesn't reproduce my problem, (compiled and run), and I personally believe that the problem lies in the function. And what do you mean by '`bar` is and automatic variable'?

Comment: @YiFei I mean that the variable has [automatic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) storage duration. My minimized example might not have the same behaviour as yours because the behaviour is undefined. Nevertheless, it demonstrates the same bug.

Comment: Note, I changed 'variable' to 'object' for better generality.

Comment: Would it be better if I store those shared_ptr in a external (with respect to instances of the struct, say in main function) container or store just bare pointers?

Comment: @YiFei It's hard to tell what is better when you haven't described *why* you use shared pointers. If you do want to maintain a shared pointer to `*bar`, then yes, you should use a shared pointer in main. And yes, if you do store a copy of `this` in a member, then that pointer should be bare. Although, weak pointer might also be an option, if all the pointers in the vector are supposed to be maintained by a shared pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Either create `a` on the stack or let a `shared_ptr` manage its lifetime, but you can't do both. Objects on the stack go away when the stack goes away.